# Are the downloads from Windows Store resumeable

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I am downloading windows upgrade. Its 2.xxGB (I don't remember right now, and neither is it being shown there) and anytime I will have to go to sleep as its almost night here, so I wanted to ask, are the downloads there resumable? I have searched Google, but the results are for Download Manager of IE :/

Any guess about it?

Comment: WYou will be unable to use a download manager for a Windows Store download.  The alternative solution is use a Windows 8.1 .iso and a generic Windows 8.1 license key ( the change the key before you variable your installation ) which is a hassle I would just leave your PC turned on

Comment: @Ramhound, hmmm, so there is no resume for the active downloads in windows store

Comment: I just said that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is resumable.
download can be cancelled for now and when it is restarted from install link on home of windows store it will resume.